# Updating MapGuide Enterprise's Query Tool

Tags: mapguide

I am trying to create a custom theme for my company's website using MapGuide Enterprise 2011, and I am looking for advice on fine-tuning the software's built-in query tool to allow for more advanced querying.

The built-in Query tool is (as far as I can tell) only able to perform a single query on a layer, however I am hoping to be able to query multiple layers/multiple queries in the same layer for more precise searching. Being able to save my query results as a selection would also be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation would be a tad different depending on what you're using: Fusion or Ajax Viewer. But mostly it'll depend on the mapguide php backend (or .net or java).

If you look at the developer's guide PDF file that comes with your MGE cd (should be available online, but make sure they're kindda newer), around page 41: Working with Feature data -> Querying Feature Data -> Example: Selection. You'll see a good example of how to do what you wanted. It's tailored towards the Ajax Viewer, but you can implement the same thing in Fusion using widgets.

It basically involves setting filters on the layers you want and adding it to the selection object per that session. You'll probably also want an html form on the client end to specify what to query.

You will want to checkout one of the API documentation here:

http://www.osgeo.org/files/mapguide/docs/2.0/index.htm